# Replace if element exist from other table sqlite3

Tags: sql, database, join, replace, sqlite

I have two tables.

table: gender_age_train

```
index       Unnamed: 0  device_id             gender      age         group       phone_brand
    ----------  ----------  --------------------  ----------  ----------  ----------  -----------
    1           0           -8076087639492063270  M           35          M32-38      小米         
    2           1           -2897161552818060146  M           35          M32-38      小米         
    3           2           -8260683887967679142  M           35          M32-38      小米         
    4           3           -4938849341048082022  M           30          M29-31      小米         
    5           4           245133531816851882    M           30          M29-31      小米         
    6           5           -1297074871525174196  F           24          F24-26      OPPO       
    7           6           236877999787307864    M           36          M32-38      酷派         
    8           7           -8098239495777311881  M           38          M32-38      小米         
    9           8           176515041953473526    M           33          M32-38      vivo       
    10          9           1596610250680140042   F           36          F33-42      三星
```

table: chinese_latin_translation

```
index       chinese     latin_brands
----------  ----------  ------------
1           三星          samsung     
2           天语          Ktouch      
3           海信          hisense     
4           联想          lenovo      
5           欧比          obi         
6           爱派尔         ipair       
7           努比亚         nubia       
8           优米          youmi       
9           朵唯          dowe        
10          黑米          heymi
```

How can I replace the `phone_brand` from the table `gender_age_train`, if the brand exist in chinese letters with the translation from the column `latin_brands`?

I want to replace not the completly column, just only the row, if a translation is available.

The dataset has more then 1mio rows. The important columns on this case are only the `phone_brand` and the `latin_brands`

Example Query:

```
SELECT latin_brands, phone_brand  FROM gender_age_brand_train LEFT JOIN chinese_latin_translation on gender_age_brand_train.phone_brand = chinese
```

Comment: Hint:  `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I tried a many versions of left join, but I dont know, how to replace or update the column. Because not every element in the column `phone_brand `has a translation. @GordonLinoff

Comment: . . You should include a sample query in the question.

Comment: sample has been added. @GordonLinoff

Comment: You want just select data or update your data?

Comment: @Indent I want to update

Answer (score 0):

Use a `left join` between : chinese_latin_translation and gender_age_train

```
select
    A.index,
    A.Unnamed,
    A.device_id,
    A.gender,
    A.age,
    A.group,
    coalesce(B.latin_brands,A.phone_brand) as brand
from 
    gender_age_train A
    left join chinese_latin_translation B on
        A.phone_brand= B.chinese
```

Answer (score 0):

this should fit with your req, Inner join with update Row

```
UPDATE  T2
SET    T2. Name = T1 .Name
FROM   gender_age_train as T2 INNER JOIN Table1 as T1
ON     T1. Id = T1 .Id;
```

now u can set your Query.